# While present navigation then presented viewcontroller bar button not coming, why in swift

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller

my viewcontroller flow will be like below:

```
  navigationcontroller -> logoutviewcontroller ->(present) 

                       viewcontroller -> (present) logoutviewcontroller (bar button coming)
                                |
                           loginviewcontroller
                                |
                        (present) logoutviewcontroller (bar button not coming)
```

logoutVC code:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()        
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))
    }


  @objc func handleLogout(){

let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

 }
```

loginVC code: when presenting logoutVC coming but bar button not coming.. why

```
 @IBAction func loginButn(_ sender: Any) {

guard  let email = emailTf.text, let password = passwordTf.text
else {
    print("form is not valid")
    return
}
Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
    
    if error != nil{
        print("login adding error: \(String(describing: error))" as Any)
        return
    }
    print("login sucessfully")
    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LogOutViewController") as! LogOutViewController
        
    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
})
}
```

please suggest here with code

Answer (score 1):

If by bar button you mean the `navigationController`'s `navigationBar`, you don't need to present the `ViewController` but you need to use

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

Comment: if i do `pushViewController ` then going no where.. staying in the login page

Comment: Check if  `navigationController` is not nil